# The Info Windows content change for Google Maps Engine cannot be adopted

Tags: google-maps-engine

When I edit the Info Window, I modified

`<a href="http://cs.sj.gov/pub/prjDetail.cfm?prj_id=+{PRJ_ID}"> View Details </a>`

as

`<a href="http://cs.sj.gov/pub/prjDetail.cfm?prj_id=+{PRJ_ID}" target="_blank"> View Details </a>`

However, in the map preview, the new attribute `target="_blank` is not added into the Info Window.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported.

Google Maps Engine supports only basic HTML for the info windows, as listed [here](https://support.google.com/mapsengine/answer/1247807).

Comment: link you provide is not saying "target" is not supported

Comment: You're right. I could have sworen that's where I seen it mentioned previously. Anyway I don't think that docco will be updated any further as the enterprise level maps engine is being deprecated in Jan 2016.

Answer (score 0):

As exposed [here](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171216?hl=en), you can take advantage of the Fusion Table features.
We have also a running example at [geocodezip.com](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_openInfowindowInParentE.html)

More details with this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13406170/195812)